# Access flink state inside processBroadcastElement function

Tags: apache-flink

Going to do some state management inside `processBroadcastElement()` function.

```
final val actvTagsMapValue = new MapStateDescriptor[String, List[String]]("actvTagsMapValue", classOf[String], classOf[List[String]])

override def processBroadcastElement(...): Unit {
    val actvTagMap = getRuntimeContext.getMapState(actvTagsMapValue)
    val st = actvTagMap.entries() // this line produce an error
}
```

Getting following error during access state

```
229797 [LabelShlfEvents -> Sink: Print to Std. Out (1/1)] WARN  
o.a.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task - LabelShlfEvents -> Sink: Print to Std. Out (1/1) 
(d3154841fd8bd4cabc00e0145ac37ed8) switched from RUNNING to FAILED. 
java.lang.NullPointerException: No key set. This method should not be called outside of a keyed context.
at org.apache.flink.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:75)
```

I am not allowed to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this. The reason is quite simple, as `MapState` (but also `ValueState`, `ListState` and more as described [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/state/state.html)) is type of state called keyed state. This state is partittioned and scoped to the input key of current element.

Broadcast elements are not keyed nor partitioned in any way, so there is no `KeyedContext` attached to those elements. When You try to access the state inside the `processBroadcastElement`, Flink has no idea which key is  this request scoped to, that's why You will get an exception.

On the other hand, You can safely use keyed state in `processElement` of `KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction`, because those element will have key assigned and the scope is known in case of keyed state.

If You need to use state for broadcast elements that is not Broadcast state, You need to implement this as operator state as described in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

That doesn't work, for the reason explained by Dominik in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67059831/2000823).

What you can do in `processBroadcastElement` is to access/modify/delete the keyed state for all keys, by using `applyToKeyedState` with a `KeyedStateFunction`. However, you must take care to behave deterministically across all parallel instances. Otherwise, after recovery or rescaling you could end up with inconsistencies.

Here's an example that emits the values of a `ValueState` for every key upon receiving any broadcast message.

```java
public static class DumpFunction
        extends KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction<Long, TaxiRide, String, TaxiRide> {
    private ValueStateDescriptor<TaxiRide> taxiDesc;
    private ValueState<TaxiRide> taxiState;
    
    @Override
    public void open(Configuration config) {
        taxiDesc = new ValueStateDescriptor<>("ride", TaxiRide.class);
        taxiState = getRuntimeContext().getState(taxiDescriptor);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void processElement(TaxiRide ride, ReadOnlyContext ctx, 
            Collector< TaxiRide> out) throws Exception {
        taxiState.update(ride);
    }
            
    @Override
    public void processBroadcastElement(String msg, Context ctx, Collector<TaxiRide> out) {
        ctx.applyToKeyedState(taxiDesc, new KeyedStateFunction<Long, ValueState<TaxiRide>>() {
            @Override
            public void process(Long taxiId, ValueState<TaxiRide> taxiState) throws Exception {
                out.collect(taxiState.value());
            }
        });
    }
}
```