# Flink: Can we update a keyed state for only some elements in processBroadcastElement function?

Tags: apache-flink

As mentioned in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67059458/access-flink-state-inside-processbroadcastelement-function), I can use `applyToKeyedState` to update all states across all keys in the same manner.

If my broadcast event has a subset of all keys and I only want to update those, can I make it a part of the KeyedStateFunction?

Example

```
ctx.applyToKeyedState(stateDescriptor, new KeyedStateFunction[K, ValueState[Boolean]]() {
      override def process(k: K, state: ValueState[Boolean]): Unit = {
        val key = k.asInstanceOf[String]

        if (broadcastEvent.contains(key)) {
          state.update(true))
        }
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing prevents you from employing whatever logic you desire in your `KeyedStateFunction`, but you could get yourself into trouble. The issue is this: each instance of your keyed broadcast function operator will be applying this function independently. And the job might crash at any point -- perhaps after some instances have applied the `KeyedStateFunction`, and others have not.

You should limit yourself to operations on the keyed state that will never give rise to inconsistencies, even after failure/recovery or after rescaling.